# How to create a list of files with relative path to the files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, terminal

So I'm writing a cli tool that takes a file and calculates a checksum(CRC32) for that file. I want my tool to have **recursion** as an option. So I want list of all files in an directory so that i can pass it as an parameter to my checksum method.

Note: 'Test Dir/' is a directory in the same folder as script and is input through terminal rather than a set variable.

So far i have:

```
rootDir = ['Test Dir/']
files = []

for i in rootDir:
    if not os.path.isdir(i):
       files.append(i)
    else:
        for dir_, _, files in os.walk(i):
            for fileName in files:
                relDir = os.path.relpath(dir_, i)
                relFile = os.path.join(relDir, fileName)
                files.append(relFile)
```

This returns:

`['./root.py', './root.txt', 'Lv1/lv1.py', 'Lv1/lv1.pyc', 'Lv1/lv1.txt', 'Lv1/Lv2/lv2.pyc', 'Lv1/Lv2/lv2.py', 'Lv1/Lv2/lv2.txt', 'Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/lv3.txt', 'Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/lv3.py', 'Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/lv3.pyc']`

But if I input rootDir as 'Test Dir/*', I get:

`['./lv1.py', './lv1.pyc', './lv1.txt', 'Lv2/lv2.pyc', 'Lv2/lv2.py', 'Lv2/lv2.txt', 'Lv2/Lv3/lv3.txt', 'Lv2/Lv3/lv3.py', 'Lv2/Lv3/lv3.pyc', 'Test Dir/root.py', 'Test Dir/root.txt']`

same files but slightly different list.

What i want is:
`['Test Dir/root.py', 'Test Dir/root.txt', 'Test Dir/Lv1/lv1.py', 'Test Dir/Lv1/lv1.pyc', 'Test Dir/Lv1/lv1.txt', 'Test Dir/Lv1/Lv2/lv2.pyc', 'Test Dir/Lv1/Lv2/lv2.py', 'Test Dir/Lv1/Lv2/lv2.txt', 'Test Dir/Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/lv3.txt', 'Test Dir/Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/lv3.py', 'Test Dir/Lv1/Lv2/Lv3/lv3.pyc']`

Now I know i can do this using string manipulation but that doesn't seem very clean...
 Really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: You treat `rootDir` as a list of strings in your `for` loop and yet you initialized it with just a string of `'TestDir/`? Are you sure you are showing us the actual code? And what does your directory structure look like? Also, the `else` block appears to need more indentation.

Comment: No this is not the actual code i actually use argparse to get rootDir. But the other points you mentioned are valid. Give me a sec I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The way `os.path.relpath` works is that it will include only the path names under the given base path, so if you want your final list to all include the base path name, you actually don't need `os.path.relpath` to begin with.

Also, the`files` variable you use for the `for` loop is shadowing the `files` list you initialized at the beginning and used within the `for` loop. Your code won't actually complete because you keep appending to the list while using it as an iterator. You should name it something else.

Your code should be corrected to something like:

```
rootDir = ['Test Dir/']
paths = []

for i in rootDir:
    if not os.path.isdir(i):
       paths.append(i)
    else:
        for dir_, _, files in os.walk(i):
            for fileName in files:
                paths.append(os.path.join(i, fileName))
```

Comment: This does not work. I see what you're saying though I'll try to work with this. Thanks. P.S. my bad for using same var name for my list and generator var :P